# String of coordinates into Openlayers-3 Linestring on Vector Layer

Tags: openlayers, coordinate-system, features, vector-layer

I getting a string of coordinates like so:

```
[[38.313072, -89.863845] ,[38.312675, -89.863586] ,[38.310405, -89.862091] ,[38.310405, -89.862091] ,[38.309913, -89.861976] ,[38.309768, -89.861976] ,[38.309768, -89.861976] ,[38.30965, -89.861991] ,[38.309558, -89.862045] ,[38.309513, -89.862121] ,[38.30949, -89.862236] ,[38.309494, -89.86235] ,[38.309562, -89.862594] ,[38.313106, -89.871429] ,[38.313892, -89.873191]]
```

I'm trying to convert this into an Openlayers-3 feature on a vector layer like so:

```
var str = [[38.313072, -89.863845] ,[38.312675, -89.863586] ......
var trnsStr = new ol.geom.LineString(lineStr);
var strPrj = ol.proj.transform(trnsStr, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
vectorRoute = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: new ol.source.Vector({
       features: new ol.Feature({
           geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(strPrj),
               name: 'Line'
       })
   })
});
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working for me.  I get 'length' errors trying to transform the geom.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`ol.proj.transform` is used to transform single Coordinates, not geometries. Use the `transform` method of each `ol.geom.Geometry` instead:

```
var str = [[38.313072, -89.863845] ,[38.312675, -89.863586] ......
var trnsStr = new ol.geom.LineString(str);
trnsStr.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
vectorRoute = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: new ol.source.Vector({
       features: new ol.Feature({
           geometry: trnsStr,
           name: 'Line'
       })
   })
});
```

Comment: that returns trnsStr as : `[object Object]`.  No errors show in debugger, but no vectorlayer is created either.

Comment: I fixed some issues with the code. Try again. If it fails, use the browsers developer tools to debug.

Comment: Yes, I already fixed those typos...  same results.  still makes them an object

Comment: Well, it is an object. And it should be. Could you describe the actual error?

Comment: No errors... but no layer.